# Printf memory allocation in dynamic language

Tags: memory-management, printf

I'm curious about clever way to implement printf() analogue in dynamic language. The problem is that arguments list can contain deeply nested datatypes, so I can't easily know how much memory should I allocate for final buffer. The obvious way to do this is to make 2 passes through arguments: one to estimate buffer size and other to actually format string. Is there any better way to do this?

CLARIFICATION: I'm thinking about writing C-function for Erlang. Erlangs' datatypes are deeply boxed, so to use asprintf-like functions I will need to unbox them all (and possibly rewrite formatstring), and that is expensive.

Comment: It would help to specify which language you are using. `printf()` only understand [a few primitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) - unless you are writing your own, you cannot pass arbitrary types to printf. Please clarify.

Comment: @Beaks - I think he means if you do something like `printf("%s", myString)`, and you're writing to a fixed-width buffer you allocate, how do you know how big to make it

Comment: @si14: Why do you need to write to a buffer? printf writes to a stream, sprintf is given a buffer that caller has to ensure is big enough

Comment: Don't dynamic languages typically have an implementation of 'dynamic arrays'? In that case, why would you need two passes? Just pass once to format, and add the formatted characters to the dynamic array as you go. The result is a formatted, dynamically allocated string which you can then print.

Comment: @ckhan I'm thinking about my own version of sprintf-like function for Erlang in C. asprintf would be dramatically inefficient because of multilevel boxing of Erlang data.

Comment: @Hassan Erlang doesn't have one. I can write them myself, but it will have cost of reallocating memory (as any dynamic array, in fact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's `printf` that you're trying to emulate, then you don't have a problem, because you don't need a buffer, you write each token to the console as you find it.

If you're trying to emulate `sprintf` then you need to update your question.

For sprintf . . . use an extensible string buffer.

If you've to roll your own, start off with a reasonable buffer of 512 bytes. As you reach the limit of this, allocate another buffer of **twice** the previous limit (so 1024 first time, 2048 second time etc), copy buffer1 to buffer2, swap your new buffer for the old and throw away/free/delete/deallocate the first buffer.

Then when you're finished, you allocate a string of the correct length, copy your buffer to the string and return it.

The last step can be ignored if you don't mind passing back the buffer as the result, even though it is technically too large and is *probably* mostly unused.

**Update**
*Feels like sub-optimal solution because of reallocation. Am I wrong?*

In a word, yes.
This is how dynamic lists & arrays are implemented in major frameworks like the C++ STL and the .Net framework. If you consider the likelihood that a format might break 512bytes, how likely is it to break 1024, or 2048? that's three extra copies, if the string ends up being that long. You can probably apply an 80/20 rule that 80% of the time you'll never hit the first 512 limit (you could probably drop the first allocation to 64 bytes and still apply the 80/20 rule)

Now consider your alternative, to make two passes over the items to be formatted.
If you have a 32bit int, you've to pretty much convert that to a string to find out how long the string is going to be. You'll do that one extra time for every item in the list, which is an allocation for a buffer to do the conversion, the time to do the conversion, and then de-allocate the string. Getting the length of an int is relatively straightforward compared to some other data types.

Also consider complex objects, if you're getting the length of those, their representations are (possibly) build up by calling some `.ToString` like method, which will concatenate the results of all it's sub objects `ToString` methods together, and again you'll be doing this twice.

Given the toss between an extensible string buffer, and building all the strings one extra time to get their lengths? I'd go with for the buffer every time.

Comment: Downvoted because there exist functions in the standard library to do this, encouraging the OP to roll his own expensive (malloc is a *very* expensive system call) exception-driven inferior solution to the problem is unwise. I have posted what I believe to be a correct answer. (Although admittedly it's unclear if the OP is using C)

Comment: @Beaks: "encouraging the OP to roll his own". Where do I encourage the  asker to roll his own? He's looking to implement this in some (unspecified) **dynamic** language. I have no idea what tools or utilities he has to hand, and simply outlined a bare bones approach if he needed one. Also, how do you know he has access to the standard library? Mate I'll take my licks where they're deserved, but I honestly don't think this one is.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier feels like suboptimal solution because of reallocation. Am I wrong? Speaking about your and Beaks argue - you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variant of `sprintf()` called `asprintf()`, this variant mallocs the space to store the resulting string, without you having to know it's length in advance.

It's available on most platforms as part of the C stdlib, you can read more (probably) with `man asprintf`, [or at this online copy of the manpage.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

Fromt the man pages:

> The printf() family of functions produces output according to a format as described below.  The printf() and vprintf() functions write
>        output to stdout, the standard output stream; fprintf() and vfprintf() write output to the given output stream; dprintf() and
>        vdprintf() write output to the given file descriptor; sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf() write to the character string
>        s; **and asprintf() and vasprintf() dynamically allocate a new string with malloc(3).**

add:

> The asprintf() and vasprintf() functions set *ret to be a pointer to a buffer sufficiently large to hold the formatted string.  This
>        pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.  If sufficient space cannot be allo-
>        cated, asprintf() and vasprintf() will return -1 and set ret to be a NULL pointer.

(bold added for emphasis)

Here's a small sample usage:

```
char *buffer;
asprintf(buffer, "Hello %s", myunknownlengthstring);
```

This should allocate, sufficient space to store the resulting formatted string and store it at `&buffer`. You will be responsible for freeing this memory, otherwise it will leak, a simple `free(buffer)` when the string is no longer needed should be sufficient.

Comment: The asker has stated that they're implementing this in a **dynamic** language. Why are you banging on about the standard c library?

Comment: I can't use asprintf because I'll need to unbox all values in my target language (I'm thinking about writing C-function for Erlang, and its' values are deeply boxed sometimes). It will be quite expensive in terms of allocating-deallocating.